# Violin plot with list input

Tags: r

I am using the vioplot funciton form the vioplot package, and I would like to feed a list as an input. So this is what I have:

```
# Violin Plots
library(vioplot)
x1 <- mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==4]
x2 <- mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==6]
x3 <- mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==8]
vioplot(x1, x2, x3, names=c("4 cyl", "6 cyl", "8 cyl"),
   col="gold")
title("Violin Plots of Miles Per Gallon")
```

And this is what I would like to do:

```
# Violin Plots
library(vioplot)
x1 <- mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==4]
x2 <- mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==6]
x3 <- mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==8]
l<-list(x1,x2,x3)
vioplot(l, names=c("4 cyl", "6 cyl", "8 cyl"),
   col="gold")
title("Violin Plots of Miles Per Gallon")
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in min(data) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

Can you help? Thanks!

Comment: A cleaner definition of `l` (bypassing the need to do all the `x`s first) is `l <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)`.

Comment: It is also possible to use the add=TRUE parameter in vioplot() and control positions with the 'at' parameter. Then an lapply() can be used to plot the list of vectors. Remember to set xlim and ylim accordingly e.g. in an empty plot at first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have modified the vioplot function to accept a list as an input, you can use this *vioplot2*:

```
vioplot2<-function (x, ..., range = 1.5, h = NULL, ylim = NULL, names = NULL, 
    horizontal = FALSE, col = "magenta", border = "black", lty = 1, 
    lwd = 1, rectCol = "black", colMed = "white", pchMed = 19, 
    at, add = FALSE, wex = 1, drawRect = TRUE) 
{
    if(!is.list(x)){
        datas <- list(x, ...)
    } else{
        datas<-x
    }
    n <- length(datas)
    if (missing(at)) 
        at <- 1:n
    upper <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
    lower <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
    q1 <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
    q3 <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
    med <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
    base <- vector(mode = "list", length = n)
    height <- vector(mode = "list", length = n)
    baserange <- c(Inf, -Inf)
    args <- list(display = "none")
    if (!(is.null(h))) 
        args <- c(args, h = h)
    for (i in 1:n) {
        data <- datas[[i]]
        data.min <- min(data)
        data.max <- max(data)
        q1[i] <- quantile(data, 0.25)
        q3[i] <- quantile(data, 0.75)
        med[i] <- median(data)
        iqd <- q3[i] - q1[i]
        upper[i] <- min(q3[i] + range * iqd, data.max)
        lower[i] <- max(q1[i] - range * iqd, data.min)
        est.xlim <- c(min(lower[i], data.min), max(upper[i], 
            data.max))
        smout <- do.call("sm.density", c(list(data, xlim = est.xlim), 
            args))
        hscale <- 0.4/max(smout$estimate) * wex
        base[[i]] <- smout$eval.points
        height[[i]] <- smout$estimate * hscale
        t <- range(base[[i]])
        baserange[1] <- min(baserange[1], t[1])
        baserange[2] <- max(baserange[2], t[2])
    }
    if (!add) {
        xlim <- if (n == 1) 
            at + c(-0.5, 0.5)
        else range(at) + min(diff(at))/2 * c(-1, 1)
        if (is.null(ylim)) {
            ylim <- baserange
        }
    }
    if (is.null(names)) {
        label <- 1:n
    }
    else {
        label <- names
    }
    boxwidth <- 0.05 * wex
    if (!add) 
        plot.new()
    if (!horizontal) {
        if (!add) {
            plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)
            axis(2)
            axis(1, at = at, label = label)
        }
        box()
        for (i in 1:n) {
            polygon(c(at[i] - height[[i]], rev(at[i] + height[[i]])), 
                c(base[[i]], rev(base[[i]])), col = col, border = border, 
                lty = lty, lwd = lwd)
            if (drawRect) {
                lines(at[c(i, i)], c(lower[i], upper[i]), lwd = lwd, 
                  lty = lty)
                rect(at[i] - boxwidth/2, q1[i], at[i] + boxwidth/2, 
                  q3[i], col = rectCol)
                points(at[i], med[i], pch = pchMed, col = colMed)
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if (!add) {
            plot.window(xlim = ylim, ylim = xlim)
            axis(1)
            axis(2, at = at, label = label)
        }
        box()
        for (i in 1:n) {
            polygon(c(base[[i]], rev(base[[i]])), c(at[i] - height[[i]], 
                rev(at[i] + height[[i]])), col = col, border = border, 
                lty = lty, lwd = lwd)
            if (drawRect) {
                lines(c(lower[i], upper[i]), at[c(i, i)], lwd = lwd, 
                  lty = lty)
                rect(q1[i], at[i] - boxwidth/2, q3[i], at[i] + 
                  boxwidth/2, col = rectCol)
                points(med[i], at[i], pch = pchMed, col = colMed)
            }
        }
    }
    invisible(list(upper = upper, lower = lower, median = med, 
        q1 = q1, q3 = q3))
}
```

What you get with your example is this:
[image]

Comment: I think we should write to the author of vioplot to notify them with this update (dadler at uni-goettingen.de)

Comment: Good idea! I just did it

Answer (score 1):

I've included the solution above in an function (R package) on Github. Should work just like input for boxplot (including formula input), includes a range of other custom features such as separate colours for each violin.

Install and load with:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("TomKellyGenetics/vioplotx")
library("vioplotx")
```

So just like you would make a boxplot:

```
# Set up data
data(mtcars)
x1 <- mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==4]
x2 <- mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==6]
x3 <- mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==8]
l<-list(x1,x2,x3)

# Boxplots
boxplot(l, names=c("4 cyl", "6 cyl", "8 cyl"), col="gold")
title("Boxplots of Miles Per Gallon")
```

[image]

You can use the "vioplotx" do do the same:

So just like you would make a violinplot:

```
# Violin plots
vioplotx(l, names=c("4 cyl", "6 cyl", "8 cyl"), col="gold")
title("Violin plots of Miles Per Gallon")
```

[image]

This also enables additional customisation with vector inputs:

```
vioplotx(l, names=c("4 cyl", "6 cyl", "8 cyl"), col=c("cyan", "magenta", "green"))
```

[image]

This is modification of Daniel Adler's "vioplot" package including change based on Federico Giorgi's answer here. This is purely intended to make running such modifications easier.

Comment: As the original vioplot package (version 0.2) has been orphaned, I have submitted these changes to the CRAN repository for review. https://github.com/TomKellyGenetics/vioplot

Comment: This version of vioplot has now been accepted on CRAN

Answer (score 1):

Here is an another solution, adding colored violins using lapply:

```
library(vioplot)

# Set up data
x1 <- mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==4]
x2 <- mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==6]
x3 <- mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==8]
l <- list(x1,x2,x3)

# Colors
mycol <- c("yellow", "green", "blue")

# Set up plot without violins
plot("", xlim = c(0.5, length(l)+0.5), ylim = c(min(unlist(l)), max(unlist(l))), xaxt = "n",  xlab = "", ylab = "Miles Per Gallon")
axis(1, labels = c("4cyl", "6cyl", "8cyl"), at = c(1:length(l)))

# Add violins from list
lapply(seq_along(l), function(x)
  vioplot(l[[x]], at = x, col = mycol[x], add = T, box = F)
  )
```

Done!

[image: Violin plots generated from list]